# UML sequence diagram - how to represent method arguments that instantiate objects

Tags: ruby, uml, sequence-diagram

I'm not sure how to represent something like the following in a sequence diagram (in Ruby):

```
 class FirstClass
   def process 
       thing = SecondClass.new('string argument', third_class, 2) 
    end 

   def third_class 
       ThirdClass.new('another string argument',)
   end
 end
```

The first message in the sequence is a call to an instance of FirstClass, and the part that's tripping me up is how to represent the ThirdClass.new being passed as an argument to the SecondClass initializer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you just show how and in which order the objects are instantiated and not where they are assigned:

[image]

So first the `ThirdClass` is created and then `SecondClass` where you pass a `ThirdClass` parameter.

I don't know the exact Ruby syntax. So the `new` is a place holder. Other languages require the class name, Python uses `__init__`, etc. But the dashed arrow line shows that's it's an object creation.